# My program checking for mouse click can be run just once

Tags: c++, dos, turbo-c++, bgi

I have made this program in Turbo C++ wherein when the user clicks inside the square that comes on screen, the program should exit. The program works fine if I run it once. But when I run it again, it exits as soon as mouse is inside the square. It does not wait for the click. I think it is something to do with resetting the mouse.

```
#include<process.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<graphics.h>
#include<dos.h>
union REGS in,out;
void main()
{
int gdriver = DETECT,gmode;
int xp,yp,cl=0;
int x,y;
 initgraph(&gdriver,&gmode,"C:\\Turboc3\\BGI");
x=getmaxx()/2;
y=getmaxy()/2;
in.x.ax=4;
in.x.cx=10;
in.x.dx=10;
int86(51,&in,&out);
in.x.ax=1;
int86(51,&in,&out);
setcolor(RED);
rectangle((x-100),(y-100),x,y);
    in.x.ax=3;
while(1)
{    
 int86(51,&in,&out);
 cl=out.x.bx;
 xp=out.x.cx;
 yp=out.x.dx;
 if(((xp>=x-100)&&(xp<=x))&&((yp>=y-100)&&(yp<=y)))
  if(cl==1)
      {
       cl=0;
   exit(1);
      }
 }
}
```

[OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L7cXn.png)

P.S. I already know that Turbo C++ is an "ancient compiler"  and I am well aware of the existence of other modern compilers, but I am forced to use this compiler.

Comment: reset the driver, indeed, call function 0 of int 33h at first. Full reference (omg, it still around): https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece390/books/labmanual/io-devices-mouse.html

Comment: @Swift I used in.x.ax=0 and int86(51,&in,&out) statements in my program at the start. I think thats what you meant right? But it doesn't work still :(

Comment: what OS you do run?

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have figured out the problem. When I start the program again, instead of dragging the mouse inside the square button straight away, if I click outside the square button first and then move towards the square button, the problem doesn't happen.
Basically, when the program starts for the 2nd time, the mouse starts with click=1 instead of click=0. I can't find out how to fix this though..

Answer (score 0):

I've found this, dunno if that would help any. Depending what your OS you're running... or is that DosBox? It uses BGI to set graphic mode which may not work if you run it from x64 windows, should work from DosBox(at least, Turbo Pascal's version does). It is curious, that program does one dummy reading of mouse status after making cursor visible, to flush the registers. Is that the gotcha you're hit by?

```
 #include<graphics.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<dos.h>

union REGS i, o;

int initmouse()
{
   i.x.ax = 0;
   int86(0X33,&i,&o);
   return ( o.x.ax );
}

void showmouseptr()
{
   i.x.ax = 1;
   int86(0X33,&i,&o);
}

void getmousepos(int *button, int *x, int *y)
{
   i.x.ax = 3;
   int86(0X33,&i,&o);

   *button = o.x.bx;
   *x = o.x.cx;
   *y = o.x.dx;
}

main()
{
   int gd = DETECT, gm, status, button, x, y;
   char array[50];

   initgraph(&gd,&gm,"C:\\TC\\BGI");
   settextstyle(DEFAULT_FONT,0,2);

   status = initmouse();

   if ( status == 0 )
      printf("Mouse support not available.\n");
   else
   {
      showmouseptr();

      getmousepos(&button,&x,&y);

      while(!kbhit())
      {
         getmousepos(&button,&x,&y);

         if( button == 1 )
         {
            button = -1;
            cleardevice();
            sprintf(array,"Left Button clicked x = %d y = %d",x,y);
            outtext(array);
         }
         else if( button == 2 )
         {
            button = -1;
            cleardevice();
            sprintf(array,"Right Button clicked x = %d y = %d",x,y);
            outtext(array);
         }

      }
   }

   getch();
   return 0;
}
```

You're doing what my boss called jokingly "Computer necrophilia". Those old systems had all kind of quirks. There were reasons why programmers of old where maniacal about initializing variables. You could run into issue that if you declare a long int variable, then assigning to it a long value, then a short value, then only lower word will be set in second case - all because compiler wasn't "casting" short to long implicitly, it was just copying binary image to the same address.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem recently and the cause is DOSBox, more precisely Turbo C++ IDE running in DOSBox. Try exiting the IDE and runnning your compiled program from the command line, it will work fine. Or try a virtualbox MS-DOS machine, it will work fine even from the IDE.

Comment: Please do not post the [same answer to multiple questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72462739/10871073).